# create celery task, but don't run until explicitly called later

Tags: python, celery

My use case is users can edit any article. If the user is not the original author then a notification asks the author for permission. If the author agrees then the update goes ahead.

I am considering creating celery task aimed at running the update function - the task can then either be run when the author agrees, or deleted if the author dismisses the change.

Is this a good use of celery? I am concerned it using a "queue" meaning that celery is better used on a FIFO/LIFO basis, rather than calling jobs by ID.

Is this a good use case for celery tasks? If nay, what is a better idea?

to confirm in pseudocode:

when user suggests update:

`task_id = my_task.delay_execution_until_called_by_id(*args)`

when owner accepts:

`get_task_by_id(task_id).run()`

Comment: If you are sending the task when author agrees and not when the article has been edited, then yes. Otherwise, you can delay sending task to this very moment.

Comment: how do we delay the task until a unknow time? can we say "until id is called"?

Comment: You know when the author agrees, since he will use one of your views. You can then send the task.

Comment: I have updated the question to better clarify what I mean

Comment: What I meant is, instead of `get_task_by_id(task_id).run()` you could call `my_task.apply_async(args=args)`. That is, you don't have to delay the task's execution when an edit suggested - you could send a task when you are _certain_ the update is needed.

Comment: From what I understand you are looking for some kind of deactivated task which you would like to activate at some later point of time? I don't think that is possible. So you might have to save/persist the task arguments instead of task id till the time user accepts an update.